# Which is faster while retrieving data from file; [with open() as, and then looping over] or [f.readlines, and then looping over]

Tags: python, performance, memory-management, file-io

I have a big files to read and process.

Which is the faster method to read the file through and process it.

```
with open('file') as file:
  for line in file:
      print line
```

OR

```
file = open('file')
lines = f.readlines()
file.close()

for line in lines:
  print line
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former can use buffered reading; the latter requires reading the entire file into memory first before it can start looping.

In general, it's a better idea to use the former; it's not going to be any *slower* than the latter and it's better on memory usage.

Comment: Does the former approach involves I/O operations after every line than the latter.?

Comment: Buffered reading means that it doesn't have to do an IO operation after *every* line - just when it empties its buffer (the size of the buffered is determined automatically). This is generally the way to go; it allows for the best mix of time and memory performance.

Answer (score -3):

If you have some line-base large file, I strongly suggest using the following lines to achieve your goal:

```
file = open('file')

for line in f.readlines():
  print line

file.close()
```

There are 2 points,

1. Read all content to memory is never a good idea, the right way is read them by trunk(line)
2. Don't call lines=f.readlines(), this will also cause reading all content to memory

PS: The former "with" statement only is short for `try:open();execept:pass`; readlines is implemented using iterator, so it won't eat all your memory.

Comment: Iterating over a file object is implemented with an iterator, so there's no reason to call `readlines()`. The `with` block also automatically closes the file when it's done with it.

Comment: @Amber Iterating over a file object is not quite a readable syntax to understand, but anyway you are right.

Comment: f.readlines() will read the whole file into memory regardless of whether you assign it to a variable or not

Comment: @gnibbler " This is often used to allow efficient reading of a large file by lines, but without having to load the entire file in memory.",  [Doc is here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: @Mayli, that quote is referring to when `readlines()` is used with the optional size hint. The quote you relevant here is "f.readlines() returns a list containing all the lines of data in the file. "

Comment: Downvote for not safely close the file object. Never give a bad example.